# How does Scrapy's download middleware handle file download requests?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, web-crawler

In Scrapy, I have used Selenium to login to obtain cookies and save them through `driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict)`, and configured the download middleware process_request. **The subsequent request to download a PDF file is also intercepted by the download middleware. I don't know how to handle the file download request in the middleware and return it in order to download the file normally**. At present, I directly return None in process_request, but the download fails. I want to know how scrapy download middleware is configured to release some requests without blocking them (**for example, I don't want to block file download requests**).

> I have configured the fields `file_urls` and `files` in the `items.py`.

```py
def process_request(self, request, spider):
          spider.driver.get(request.url) #访问原始请求页面
          #获取加载完成的页面代码
          detail_code = spider.driver.page_source
          try:
               
                if "pdf" in request.url: #访问pdf页面直接返回
                      spider.logger.info("当前正在拦截下载请求")
                      #对于pdf下载地址请求直接返回，但是该Response返回也无法正常下载
                      # res = Response(url=request.url,body=detail_code,encoding='utf-8',request=request,headers={"key":spider.key}) # 无法下载pdf
                      return None
                      # res = None
                else: #访问其他页面直接返回
                      spider.logger.info("当前正在拦截详细页请求")
                      res = HtmlResponse(url=request.url,encoding='utf-8',body=detail_code,request=request,headers={"key":spider.key})
                      # return request
                return res
          except TimeoutException:
            spider.logger.error("time out -> 访问超时")
          except NoSuchElementException:
            spider.logger.error("no such element -> 没有此元素")
        return None
```

I want to know how scrapy download middleware is configured to release some requests without blocking them (*for example, I don't want to block file download requests*) so that **I can download the file by requesting the file URL normally**.